# Javascript Issues - Using SQLite & jQuery to build a List

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, html-lists

I am trying to use SQLite & jQuery in javascript to build up a html list but I think I'm slightly out of my depth here...

I have a div in my html page that I am trying to populate with a ul tag followed by li tags generated from reading DB entries. The problem seems to be that the page is generated before the DB reading has returned results.

This is what I have. On the HTML page index:

```
<div id="divBody"></div>
```

I have a javascript file linked as follows:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

At the top of Common.js I have the following:

```
var db = openDatabase("Favourites", "1.0", "Favourites", 200000);
var selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM Favourites ORDER BY id";
var dataset;
var favList = "Test";

/*Page Start*/
$(document).ready(function () {

    favList = showRecords();

    $("#frmSystemInfo").submit(function () {
          var data = buildList();
          $("#divBody").html(data);
          return false;
    });
    $("#frmSystemInfo").submit();
});
```

The two functions are as follows:

```
function buildList() {
    var appsHTML += "<ul id='favouritelist'>";
    alert('favList: '+favList);
    if (favList == '') {
        appsHTML += "<!-- Empty List -->";
    } else {
        appsHTML += favList;
    }
    appsHTML += "</ul>";
}
```

Then, the function for reading the DB is as follows:

```
function showRecords()
{
    var favItems = "";

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(selectStatement, [], function (tx, result) {

            dataset = result.rows;

            for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {

                item = dataset.item(i);

                favItems += "<li role='" + item['uri'] + "' id='" + item['id'] + "'> <img src='" + item['img'] + "' alt='" + item['name'] + "'> <div class='fav-title'> " + item['name'] + " </div> </li>";
                alert('favItems: '+favItems);

            }
            favList = favItems;
            alert(favList : '+favList );
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is in the function buildList the variable favList is returning as undefined. When the page is loaded then the alerts from showRecords are displayed but at that stage it's too late.

Why is it that showRecords() is executed after buildList() even though it is called first?

Sorry if this is a really basic question, not very sharp at this stuff. I copied a lot of this stuff from another example and it had a $(document).ready function that seems to read the DB ok before showing the page.

Am I doing something very wrong here?

Cheers,
mcquaim

Comment: Anyone any ideas to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using setTimeout commands to delay the code from moving along before the results had been returned.

I have gone down a different route however, a fried showed me how to call a jim script that I was able to specify the db location on the server. This too has it's issues lol..